# My code seems to be looping and I don't know why

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am writing a program that draws an object in different states.  The first is a gray rectangle, the second is an image, and the third is a lighter rectangle with text in it.  I wrote the code as 3 classes.  I am having an issue with my component class.  It keeps looping for some reason.  When i enter a 1, it works fine.  When I enter a 2, it ask for my input 4 times before it shows the image.  When I enter a 3, It ask twice before it shows the lighter rectangle but it does not have any text.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class ImageComponent extends JComponent {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public int status;

    public int getInput(){  
    Scanner userinput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Select the state <1-rectangle, 2-image, 3-rectangle with text>");
    int state=userinput.nextInt();
    //userinput.close();
    return state;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2 =(Graphics2D) g;

        if (getInput() ==1){
            ImageMaker rectangle = new ImageMaker(0,0,500,400);
            g2.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            rectangle.draw(g2);

        }
        else if (getInput() ==2){
            Image img1 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("balloon.gif");
            ImageMaker image = new ImageMaker(img1, 0, 0, this);
            image.draw(g2);
        }
        else{
            ImageMaker rectangle = new ImageMaker(0,0,500,400);
            g2.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            rectangle.draw(g2);
            g2.drawString("Your Text Here", 500/2, 400/2);
        }   
    }

}
```

Comment: How are you calling these methods?

Answer (score 3):

I can't tell for sure the exact cause of your problems, since you've not posted a valid [minimal example program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (please check the link to see what I mean), but I have several suspicions that I'll relay to you:

- You're mixing Scanner initialized to System.in, a tool for getting input from the console, with a Swing GUI, two things that don't mix well together and **shouldn't** be mixed well together. Scanner input methods block program flow, something that can completely freeze your Swing GUI.
- You appear to be doing more things in paintComponent than you should be doing.  This method is for painting and painting only, and should not be used for file input/output (such as reading in images), for program logic, or for creating GUI components.

Answer (score 2):

> When i enter a 1, it works fine. When I enter a 2, it ask for my input 4 times before it shows the image. When I enter a 3, It ask twice before it shows the lighter rectangle but it does not have any text.

You are placing a method `getInput()` which prompts using Scanner into your `paintComponent`.  Try not to place any other stuff in your `paintComponent` method other then tasks related to painting. The paint manager will decide when to call the `paintComponent` itself and you have no absolute control over it. (For example, it may be invoked when you resize/mouseover your frame, causing your prompts to be invoked more than what you intended).

I would advise you to separate your logic for prompting the user and painting the component. Furthermore, you should avoid mixing using Scanner with custom painting.

You may consider using Dialogs: [How to make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Answer (score 0):

First: As @Hovercraft-Full-Of-Eels already noted: `paintComponent` is for painting your component, not for user interaction.

This method will be called from swing anytime it thinks it's necessary to repaint your UI - for example after your frame has been obscured by some other window and is shown again.

---

The second point is that

```
if (getInput() ==1){
```

asks for user input. If the user enters `2` the condition is not fulfilled, and with

```
else if (getInput() ==2){
```

you are asking a second time for user input.

If you have a decision chain that depends on interactive user input it should look something like

```
int input = getInput();
if (input == 1) {
    //...
} else if (input == 2) {
    //...
} else {
    //...
}
```

or

```
switch (getInput()) {
case 1:
    //...
    break;
case 2:
    //...
    break;
default:
    //...
    break;
}
```